# Fabric.js - fabric.loadSVGFromURL gives TypeError: n.reviver is not a function

Tags: fabricjs

We've been using the library for a while and we ran into some trouble while trying to scale some png/jpeg icons down a lot. The result would be blurry images regardless of what we tried. Therefore we decided that .svg were the way to go. When trying to load a .svg using the fabric.loadSVGFromURL() function the console replies with a ' TypeError: n.reviver is not a function'. The reason we wanna use the fabric.loadSVGFromURL() instead of the fabric.Image.fromURL() is that it seems that the latter only shows a single part of the .svg instead of the whole group. As can be seen here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ui64r.jpg

So when we tried to solve this issue we ran into the 'Type Error'. And now we are stuck. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

################### EDIT - CODE ADDED ###################

```
let addFurnitureToCanvas = (canvas, iconURL, noOfTables, iconName) => {
    let addedItems = addedFurniture.get();

    for (let i = 0; i < noOfTables; i++) {
        fabric.loadSVGFromURL(iconURL, function(objects, options) { 

            let furniture = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
            removeScalingCapabilities(furniture);

            canvas.add(furniture);
            addedItems.push(furniture);
        }, { crossOrigin: 'anonymous'});
    }
    canvas.renderAll();
};
```

```
TypeError: n.reviver is not a function
    at fabric.js:1
    at Function.fromElement (fabric.js:1)
    at fabric.ElementsParser.e.createObject (fabric.js:1)
    at fabric.js:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at fabric.ElementsParser.e.createObjects (fabric.js:1)
    at fabric.ElementsParser.e.parse (fabric.js:1)
    at Object.parseElements (fabric.js:1)
    at Object.h.parseSVGDocument (fabric.js:1)
    at i (fabric.js:1)
```

Comment: Please create a  jsfiddle or stackbitz so we can help you there  or post your code which is adding that  that image/ svg on canvas

Comment: I've added the code now used that produces the error. And I've also added the error code.

Answer (score 1):

missing parameter reviveropt: loadSVGFromURL(url, callback, reviveropt, optionsopt)

```
for (let i = 0; i < noOfTables; i++) {
    fabric.loadSVGFromURL(iconURL, function(objects, options) { 

        let furniture = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
        removeScalingCapabilities(furniture);

        canvas.add(furniture);
        addedItems.push(furniture);
    }, null, { crossOrigin: 'anonymous'});
}
```